# When the tree-like resolution size is the same with general(regular) resolution size？

Tags: reference-request, sat, proof-complexity, resolution

**Background:**
For an unsatisfiable SAT formulas, the length of a resolution refutaion means the number of clauses in it.
It's well known that there exist exponential separation between tree-like and general resolution length. 
i.e. there are some unsatisfiable SAT formulas whose shortest general resolution refutation length is $S$, while the shortest tree-like resolution refutation length is $2^{\Omega(S/logS)}$. see

- Ben-Sasson*, E., Impagliazzo†, R. & Wigderson‡, A. [Near Optimal Separation Of Tree-Like And General Resolution.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220442116_Near_Optimal_Separation_Of_Tree-Like_And_General_Resolution) Combinatorica 24, 585–603 (2004).

**Problem:**
Conversely, I am wondering for what kind of unsatifiable SAT formulas, the shortest tree-like and general resolution refutation length is the same/polynomially?

**My purpose:**
My purpose is to get the lower bound of general(regular) resolution for an unsatisfiable SAT formula. By far I have get the lower bound of tree-like resolution.and I want to show there's no big separation in my SAT instance to  get the lower bound of general(regular) resolution.
However, I have not found any articles about In what situation the separation is small.

Comment: Do you want to prove a lower bound for general or for regular resolution?

Comment: @notautogenerated Exactly lower bound for regular resolution. Since general size is always $\leq$ regular size.  If I can get lower bound for general resolution, it makes sense.

Comment: They are the same up to a polynomial speedup e.g. for all CNF that require size $2^{\Omega(n)}$ in general resolution, or that have polynomial-size tree-like resolution refutations. However, I guess this is not very helpful; I am not aware of any easily recognizable class of CNF where the speedup is only polynomial.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I am not clear of "polynomial speedup". Could you please explain it?

Comment: I mean that the size of a tree-like proof is polynomial in the size of the smallest general resolution proof, as you want in the question

Comment: To rephrase Emil's comment, the cases where we know there is no large separation are those where we can already prove upper or lower bounds by other means. I would probably try to prove a width lower bound and use BenSasson--Widgerson.